# Получить необходимую строку со сгруппированного списка

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

Имеется список элементов, следующего вида:

```
public class ParentChild
{
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Child { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ParentChild> list = new List<ParentChild>()
        {
        new ParentChild{Parent = "parent1", Child = "child1"},
        new ParentChild{Parent = "parent1", Child = "child2"},
        new ParentChild{Parent = "parent1", Child = "child3"},
        new ParentChild{Parent = "parent2", Child = "child1"},
        new ParentChild{Parent = "parent2", Child = "child2"},
        new ParentChild{Parent = "parent3", Child = "child2"},
        };
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Необходимо получить строку примерно следующего вида:

"parent1: child1, child2, child3
parent2: child1, child2
parent3: child2"

Получилось сделать с помощью groupby, а затем через foreach

```
var listGroup = list.GroupBy(p => p.Parent)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Parent = x.Key,
                Child = x.Select(y => y)
            });

string s = string.Empty;

foreach (var group in listGroup)
{
    s +=  group.Parent + ": ";
    foreach (var child in group.Child)
    {
        s += child.Child + ", ";
    }
    s += "\n";
}
```

Но вот хотелось бы не через foreach, а как-нибудь попроще. Через linq может тоже есть вариант и чтобы лишних запятых не было. Как-то получается после groupby анонимный тип, с которым нормально работать не получается. МОжет можно как-то к типизированному списку это преобразовать и вывеести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам решение в одну строчку, как вы хотели:

```
var listGroup = list.GroupBy(p => p.Parent);
var outText = string.Join("\n", listGroup.Select(g => g.Key + " : " + string.Join(", ", g.Select(pch => pch.Child))));
Console.Write(outText);
```

Используем [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
var g = list.GroupBy(x => x.Parent);
foreach (var item in g)
{
    var childList = item.Select(i => i.Child).Aggregate((i, j) => i + ", " + j);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " : " + childList);
}
```

Output

```
parent1 : child1, child2, child3
parent2 : child1, child2
parent3 : child2
```

Comment: Во-первых, ответ не должен состоять только из кода. Во-вторых, накопительная строковая конкатенация есть зло, в таких случаях надо использовать `StringBuilder` или `string.Join`